# Count the number of duplicate grouped by ID pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate question, but here it goes.

Assuming I have the following table:

```
import pandas

lst = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5] 
lst2 = ['A','A','B','D','E','A','A','A','E'] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst, lst2)), 
               columns =['ID', 'val'])
```

will output the following table

```
+----+-----+
| ID | Val |
+----+-----+
| 1  | A   |
+----+-----+
| 1  | A   |
+----+-----+
| 1  | B   |
+----+-----+
| 2  | D   |
+----+-----+
| 2  | E   |
+----+-----+
| 3  | A   |
+----+-----+
| 3  | A   |
+----+-----+
| 4  | A   |
+----+-----+
| 5  | E   |
+----+-----+
```

The goal is count the duplicates on VAL grouped by ID:

```
+----+-----+--------------+
| ID | Val | is_duplicate |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 1  | A   | 1            |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 1  | A   | 1            |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 1  | B   | 0            |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 2  | D   | 0            |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 2  | E   | 0            |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 3  | A   | 1            |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 3  | A   | 1            |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 4  | A   | 0            |
+----+-----+--------------+
| 5  | E   | 0            |
+----+-----+--------------+
```

I tried the following code but its counting the overall duplicates

```
 df_grouped = df.groupby(['notes']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

while the following code does only the duplicate count

```
 df.duplicated(subset=['notes'])
```

what would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: added reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `duplicated`

```
df['is_dup']=df.duplicated(subset=['ID','val'],keep=False).astype(int)
df
Out[21]: 
   ID val  is_dup
0   1   A       1
1   1   A       1
2   1   B       0
3   2   D       0
4   2   E       0
5   3   A       1
6   3   A       1
7   4   A       0
8   5   E       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.groupby` on the relevant columns and get the `count`. Then if you add `>1` to the end, then that will mean the value for the specified group contains duplicates. The > 1 will create a `boolean` `True`/`False` data type. Finally, to change to 1 or 0, simply use `.astype(int)` to transform the data type from a `boolean` data type to an `int`, which changes `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`:

```
df['is_duplicate'] = (df.groupby(['ID','val'])['val'].transform('count') > 1).astype(int)

Out[7]: 
   ID val  is_duplicate
0   1   A             1
1   1   A             1
2   1   B             0
3   2   D             0
4   2   E             0
5   3   A             1
6   3   A             1
7   4   A             0
```

Comment: thank you for the help but I think df.duplicated is a cleaner approach.